# How to disable log4j debug-logging for http-api of com.spotify.docker-client

Tags: java-8, log4j, spotify-docker-client

Using log4j 1.2.17 and com.spotify.docker-client 6.1.1 in Java8. If i set log4j root log level in DEBUG, then http-api of docker client write in log many messages like

```
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:113 - http-outgoing-13 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Api-Version: 1.37
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Docker-Experimental: false
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Ostype: linux
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Server: Docker/18.03.1-ce (linux)
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 06:42:50 GMT
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
09:42:50,624 DEBUG jersey-client-async-executor-0 headers:onResponseReceived:116 - http-outgoing-13 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I don`t understand how to disable it. All my tries:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.jersey-client-async-executor-0=INFO
log4j.logger.com.sun.jersey=INFO
log4j.logger.com.spotify=INFO
```

And this doesn't stop it. How can i disable DEBUG-loggin of jersey-client-async-executor-0 ? Thanks.

Comment: you are confusing me. you are setting the debugger but you dont want it. then just comment it out....  maybe just rephrase what your problem is and what you are looking for.

Comment: I want see a debug-message from classes, but don't wan't see it for some not interesting classes (for me) like jersey-client.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the log level to **Debug** and then you are logging on the logger the `jersey-client`, thus it is getting set on Debug level as well.

Either set your rootlogger to a different level or dont add the jersey-client to the logger.

Answer (score 0):

In `log4j` all the user defined loggers inherit from their parents and all loggers are either direct or indirect child of the `rootLogger.`

In order to stop your logger to inherit from a parent add this to your code:

```
log4j.additivity.jersey-client-async-executor-0=false
```

this will allow you to define whichever log level you want for this particular component and only the one you define. So all you need is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.jersey-client-async-executor-0=INFO, stdout
log4j.additivity.jersey-client-async-executor-0=false
```

note you can also set different appenders for each logger you define.